# Error by reading simple Json File - The getter 'visible' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

First of all, I am new to flutter, dart and also StackOverflow..

I just wanted to experience some first insights to flutter and parsing a json file.
However I am getting an error, that the getter 'visible' was called on null.

By going to the debug mode in flutter, I can clearly see all the data provided from the API, but the frontend just shows nothing.
Just the mentioned error in the debug console.

This is the very simple code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'JSON',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('JSON'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
              future: fetchListUser(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  List<User> users = snapshot.data;
                  return ListView(
                    children: users.map((user) {
                      Text('UserName: ${user.username}');
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<List<User>> fetchListUser() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List users = json.decode(response.body);
    return users.map((user) => User.fromJson(user)).toList();
  } else
    throw Exception('Failed to Load Users');
}

class User {
  final int id;
  final String name, username, email, phone, website;
  final Adresse adress;
  final Company company;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.adress,
    this.company,
    this.email,
    this.phone,
    this.username,
    this.website,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      adress: Adresse.fromJson(json['address']),
      company: Company.fromJson(json['company']),
      email: json['email'],
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      phone: json['phone'],
      username: json['username'],
      website: json['website'],
    );
  }
}

class Adresse {
  final String street, suite, zipcide;
  final Geo geo;

  Adresse({this.geo, this.street, this.suite, this.zipcide});

  factory Adresse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Adresse(
      geo: Geo.fromJson(json['geo']),
      street: json['street'],
      suite: json['suite'],
      zipcide: json['zipcode'],
    );
  }
}

class Geo {
  final String lat, lng;

  Geo({this.lat, this.lng});

  factory Geo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Geo(
      lat: json['lat'],
      lng: json['lng'],
    );
  }
}

class Company {
  final String name;
  final String catchPhrase;
  final String bs;

  Company({this.bs, this.catchPhrase, this.name});

  factory Company.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Company(
      bs: json['bs'],
      catchPhrase: json['catchPhrase'],
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

Its really just building some classes for the json structure and then I just wanted to output something.

Can anybody help me? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Check this url. The answer is in [here](https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9).  In your case missed itemCount param of Listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning a widget when you iterate over `users` in your `users.map()`.

Change:

```dart
users.map((user) {
    Text(
      'UserName: ${user.username}',
    );
  }).toList()
```

To:

```dart
users.map((user) {
    return Text(
      'UserName: ${user.username}',
    );
  }).toList()
```